# How to disable Windows 10 mobile feedback

Tags: windows-10-mobile, feedback

How can I disable Windows 10 Mobile feedback. It get's started when I press Power Button  + Lower Volume key (accidently).
Is there any way to uninstall 'Windows Feedback' from applist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OS Build 10.0.14372.0, 'Windows Feedback' app is removed and another app with name 'Feedback Hub' is introduced. And imp thing is , we can uninstall this app. Long press on 'Feedback Hub' and Select Unistall. Now Power + Volume Low will not open feedback page. 
But then, you will not see this app in store, even search can't find it. 
This app was also eating up device battery ~14% (checked for 24 Hrs).

Answer (score 1):

- You can change the frequency of how often Windows 10 requests feedback from the Settings app. To open it, click or tap the Start button and then select “Settings”.
- Click or tap the “Privacy” icon in the Settings app.
- Select “Feedback & diagnostics” in the sidebar here. If you don’t see the option, you’ll need to scroll down in the sidebar until you do.
- The “Windows should ask for my feedback” option under “Feedback frequency” controls how often Windows 10 asks for feedback. By default, it’s set to “Automatically (Recommended)”. You can also set it to “Always”, “Once a day”, or “Once a week”.
- Select “Never” and Windows 10 shouldn’t ask you to provide feedback anymore.

Comment: Even after doing this, The windows feedback app opens when I press power key+volume down key.